# htaccess redirect image calls for a certain folder to a PHP file

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I would like to redirect certain calls for images on a folder to a PHP file. For example, calls that come for:

```
example.com/news/123-hitachi.jpg
```

should go to:

```
example.com/image.php?i=123-hitachi.jpg
```

or something similar like that. It would also be cool if I would add some more variables in the URI like:

```
example.com/news/345/hitachi.jpg
```

so that the .PHP would receive 2 or more parameters.

How can I achieve that?

**EDIT:**
It should only rewrite SOME pictures, for example that come with a special folder in it like:

```
example.com/SPECIAL/parameter/id/bogus_filename.jpg
```

Comment: Please be more specific: 1) How you want to rewrite (internal redirect) `example.com/news/345/hitachi.jpg` 2) should it rewrite ALL images .. or only some (if so -- what is the condition)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for your "also cool if" case: example.com/news/345/hitachi.jpg
Requests for jpg images in `/news` are rewritten. The parameter `i` receives the image number.  The parameter `p` receives the rest of the image filename.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(news)/([0-9]+)/(.*)\.jpg$ /image.php?i=$2&p=$3 [L,QSA]
```